# linux append missing qoutes to csv fields/header

Tags: linux, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
id,"path",score,"file"
1,"/tmp/file 1.csv",5,"file 1.csv"
2,"/tmp/file2.csv",15,"file2.csv"
```

I want to convert it to:

```
"id","path","score","file"
"1","/tmp/file 1.csv","5","file 1.csv"
"2","/tmp/file2.csv","15","file2.csv"
```

How can I do it using `sed`/`awk` or any another linux tool?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to quote all entries, coma is separator, and there are no white spaces between separator and entry (this one can be solved as well but for brevity I didn't include it).

```sh
$ cat csv1 | sed -e 's/^/\"/' -e 's/$/\"/' -e 's/,/\",\"/g' -e 's/\"\"/\"/g' > csv2
```

It replaces beginning `^`, end `$` of line, `,` with `"` and at the end removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), if you run

```
mlr --csv --quote-all cat input.csv >output.csv
```

you will have

```
"id","path","score","file"
"1","/tmp/file 1.csv","5","file 1.csv"
"2","/tmp/file2.csv","15","file2.csv"
```